# geolocation marker javascript error does not show map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

https://github.com/ChadKillingsworth/geolocation-marker/releases/tag/v2.0.4

error java script it loads but soon appears error

> Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError
>   *https:*//developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error"js:34:391
>
> Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys
>   *https*://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

[image: CONSOLE ERROR]

Comment: You need to rework your question to be specific to the problem you are trying to solve, and provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: "Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error"js:34:391

"Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys"

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error create key developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key